# SharePoint Asset Register Template / Product

Tags: 2013, 2007

Currently using SharePoint 2007 Standard with a pending upgrade into SharePoint Online.

Can anyone advise of any off the shelf products that'll deal with Asset Registration?  I'm more than aware that this sort of thing can easily be done OOB with custom lists / forms but I've been asked to provide some alternative paid / commercial for comparison.

I'll be checking SharePointReviews of course but if anyone has used such a product and had a good experience with it, it would be useful to know of it.

Thanks in advance
Steven

Answer (score 0):

a bit later I know but I was looking for an Asset Register and was also trying the new Access 2013 Web App functionality as a replacement for InfoPath forms - it turns out that Access now has an Asset Tracker app template, and you can use it to create an app backed by automatic Azure DB in O365! You can always get a trial of O365 and install Office 2013 on a VM if you need to.

It may well be useful as an app for you as well as proving off the tech - am hoping that Access will continue to be developed for the "forms app of choice" as it def makes sense for relational DB RAD forms dev (and probably more accessible for most than LightSwitch)! See an unusually hands-on tech demo from SPConf2014 at http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/SharePoint-Conference/2014/SPC338

I know its not a paid app but it is the start of an extensible solution which is also commercially viable now. How about it, and what would you like in an Asset Reg that isn't in it?

Cheers, Phil.